# Maximize Office Fabric UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, office-ui-fabric

I didn't find any documentation over resizing [Office Fabric Ui Dialog](https://dev.office.com/fabric/Dialog). I need to have a button near 'close' so the Dialog box can be Maximized and resized to original place. Can anybody suggest a way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from the Fabric team here.

The Dialog now includes a `topButtonProps` prop, which can be used to add additional buttons to the top:

```
<Dialog
  ...
  topButtonsProps={ [{
    key: 'More',
    buttonType: ButtonType.icon,
    icon: 'More',
    ariaLabel: 'More',
    onClick: this._onMoreButtonClicked.bind(this)
  }] }
>
  Dialog content.
</Dialog>
```

Which results in a new command being added like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from extending Fabric components with your own CSS and JavaScript customizations from the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core).

If there are features that you think would be helpful you can make requests here: https://trello.com/b/sPTXiMzG/office-ui-fabric-core-requests